# Data values from CURL response using Python

Tags: python, json, curl

I am trying to retrieve the value of analysisId i.e. "analysisId": "AXOz36M_15JClUcAhjHN" which is in the curl output in form of json. Below is the curl output in json:

```
{"task": {"id":"AXOz36Dz2jVLWX7bQ9po","type":"REPORT","componentId":"AXOzznGH2jVLWX7bQ9pe","componentKey":"dotsonar","componentName":"dotsonar","componentQualifier":"TRK","analysisId":"AXOz36M_15JClUcAhjHN","status":"SUCCESS","submittedAt":"2020-08-03T12:30:44+0200","submitterLogin":"admin","startedAt":"2020-08-03T12:30:44+0200","executedAt":"2020-08-03T12:30:47+0200","executionTimeMs":2890,"logs":false,"hasScannerContext":true,"organization":"default-organization","branch":"patch-1","branchType":"SHORT","warningCount":0,"warnings":[]}}
```

I have tried the following

```
curl -sk "$SONAR_TOKEN:***********" "$url" | python -c 'import sys, json; print(json.load(sys.stdin)[0][6]["analysisId"])')
```

**Error**

[image]

Can anyone help me the correct python command to get the value of analysisId. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why python? Use `jq` command line if you want to do in command line

Comment: `jq '.task.analysisId' data.json` assume the json is in the `data.json`

Comment: note: when I use `echo` instead of the `curl` (to echo the exact JSON you have in the question), the `json.load` works just fine. This makes me suspect the output of your `curl` may be a bit different.

Comment: @bigbounty I know with **jq** its easy and we are able to get the value of analysisId, but for our use case we need to use python only. Thank you.

Comment: @Adam.Er8 curl output is same what i have posted in my question. Could you please share the script that worked for you.

Comment: echo '{"task": {"id":"id","type":"REPORT","componentId":"AXOzznGH2jVLWX7bQ9pe","componentKey":"dotsonar","componentName":"dotsonar","componentQualifier":"TRK","analysisId":"AXOz36M_15JClUcAhjHN","status":"SUCCESS","submittedAt":"2020-08-03T12:30:44+0200","submitterLogin":"admin","startedAt":"2020-08-03T12:30:44+0200","executedAt":"2020-08-03T12:30:47+0200","executionTimeMs":2890,"logs":false,"hasScannerContext":true,"organization":"default-organization","branch":"patch-1","branchType":"SHORT","warningCount":0,"warnings":[]}}' | python -c 'import sys, json; print(json.load(sys.stdin))'

Comment: (it was too long so I shortened a few attributes, I hope it is copy-pastable)

Comment: Well I copy-pasted it back into my terminal and got the JSON, and can add accessors like `["task"]["type"]` and get the correct output (`REPORT` in this case), I have no idea why it isn't working for you...

Comment: But the point being, your `python -c` part is correct, that's the way to parse a JSON straight from stdin, and this is why I suspect the output of curl is somewhat different.

Answer (score -1):

try using *json.loads* method instead of *json.load* (the first one used to process strings as input while the second one works with files)

Comment: @aintghost Thank you for the solution. But, it is not working and I got the new error.

Comment: @souravatta That might be a different problem, we could try to solve it if you provide any details. By the way, if your CURL response looks exactly as you showed in your post, to get _analysisId_ you could use `print(json.loads(sys.stdin)['task']['analysisId'])`

Comment: **Error**  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
TypeError: expected string or buffer

Comment: `loads` expects a string, and `sys.stdin` is a file-like object (like `load` expects)

Comment: @Adam.Er8 that's right, my bad. `loads` will be usefull with `sys.stdin.read()` only, and it will lead to the same result

Comment: @souravatta I agree with @Adam.Er8 [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63228914/data-values-from-curl-response-using-python/63229150?noredirect=1#comment111807601_63228914).  

Saved your json into test.json and executed `cat test.json | python -c 'import sys, json; print(json.load(sys.stdin)["task"]["analysisId"])'` - everythings works good, so you need to look closely to the reply you get from your request